# How to add dynamically created script tag attribute in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, load

I am trying to add `data-client-key` in my dynamically created JavaScript attribute. Check below code what I have tried:

```
var script = document.createElement("script")
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = 'https://app.example.com/snap/script.js';
//script.data-client-key="CLIENT-KEY-HERE"; /* showing error message */
document.getElementsByTagName(script)[0].setAttribute("data-client-key", "CLIENT-KEY-HERE"); /* Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined */
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

My output should be like below when I inspect element:

```
<script src="https://app.example.com/snap/script.js" data-client-key="CLIENT-KEY-HERE"></script>
```

Comment: The newly-created script element is not in the DOM before you insert it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
document.getElementsByTagName(script)[0].setAttribute("data-client-key", "CLIENT-KEY-HERE");
```

to

```
script.setAttribute("data-client-key", "CLIENT-KEY-HERE");
```

as you already have your script element in `script` variable

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the following [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) for setAttribute. You can do like this

```
b.setAttribute("name", "helloButton");
```